# Error in template processing

Tags: email-templates, ce-1.9.1.0

I have upgrading from Magento CE 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1

And I have an error into transactional email as example:

---

{Error in template processing}
You have been successfully subscribed to the newsletter.

### {Error in template processing}

I seems to be related to the header and footer.

I have tested to configure transactional email : System -> Configuration -> Design -> Transactional Emails -> Email Footer Template

But It is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I have found where was my issue. The problem was into the code I had modified in app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email.

I have updated these classes and It is working as expected now.